# how can we show a div on top of div which is positioned using transform css

Tags: html, css

How can we show a div on top of div which is positioned using transform CSS property? I want to display handlers always on top of other cells. In the below sample, I always want to show ltHandler, rbHandler on top of any other divs? Can we override(display on top) CSS transform positioned elements with other cells using z-index or any other way?

```html
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Page Title</title>
    
        <style>
            .row {
                position: absolute;
                height: 28px;
            }
    
            .cell {
                display: inline-block;
                position: absolute;
                width: 150px;
                height: 150px;
                color: red;
                border: 1px solid black;
            }
    
            .left-top-handler,
            .right-bottom-handler {
                width: 20px;
                height: 20px;
                border-radius: 50%;
                background-color: red;
                position: absolute;
                z-index: 999 !important;
                cursor: nwse-resize;
                touch-action: none;
            }
    
            .left-top-handler {
                left: -10px;
                top: -10px;
            }
    
            .right-bottom-handler {
                right: -10px;
                bottom: -10px;
            }
    
            #cell1 {
                left: 0px;
            }
    
            #cell2 {
                left: 150px;
            }
    
            #cell3 {
                left: 300px;
            }
    
            #row2 {
                
                transform: translateY(150px);
            }
    
            #row3 {
                
                transform: translateY(300px);
            }
    
            #row3 .cell{
                background-color:yellow;
                
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    
    
        <div id="row1" class="row">
           <div id="cell1" class="cell">
               <div>fjsdjkfgjk</div>
           </div>
           <div id="cell2" class="cell">
               <div>fjsdjkfgjk</div>
           </div>
    
           <div id="cell3" class="cell">
               <div>fjsdjkfgjk</div>
           </div>
       </div>
    
        <div id="row2" class="row">
           <div id="cell1" class="cell">
               <div>fjsdjkfgjk</div>
           </div>
           <div id="cell2" class="cell">
               <div>fjsdjkfgjk</div>
               <div id="ltHandler" class='left-top-handler handler'></div>
               <div id="rbHandler" class='right-bottom-handler handler'></div>
           </div>
    
           <div id="cell3" class="cell">
               <div>fjsdjkfgjk</div>
           </div>
       </div>
    
    
        <div id="row3" class="row">
            <div id="cell1" class="cell">
                <div>row3 cell1</div>
            </div>
            <div id="cell2" class="cell">
                <div>row3 cell2</div>
            </div>
    
            <div id="cell3" class="cell">
                <div>row3 cell3</div>
            </div>
        </div>

    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: for this particular case you can increase the z-index of the second row

Answer (score 0):

Set `row3` `z-index` to `-1` like this

```
#row3 {
    transform: translateY(300px);
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Comment: z-index on row3 is working. But i need to aplly same style on all rows. because in my requirement handlers can be on any row.

Comment: Then try to make that red bubble using `::before` pseudo code.